# Handling 403 error in generic way in aurelia (typeScript)

Tags: typescript, generics, error-handling, aurelia, http-status-code-403

Is there any way of handling 403 responses  sending from server in generic way  without handling each of them separately inside catch block?`

```
  searchCustomer(customerName: string): any {
            if (customerName != "") {
                let url = '{url}';
                let headers = new Headers();
                headers.append('accept', 'application/vnd.vetserve.customerlookup.v1.hal+json');
                return this.http.fetch(url, { method: 'GET', headers: headers })
                    .then(response => response.json())
                    .catch(error => {
                        if(error.status==403){
                           this._messageService.showMessage('No permission', MessageService.type.error, error);
                     }
                        console.log(error);
                    }
                        );
            }
        }`
```

Comment: Look at configuring interceptors - http://aurelia.io/hub.html#/doc/article/aurelia/fetch-client/latest/http-services/3

Comment: Actually what i need is something like calling to a  method automatically when 403 comes

Comment: Yes - you can use an interceptor to look at the header statuses, and then call whatever methods you need.

Comment: @thebluefox yes that was the perfect answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks @thebluefox for suggesting the interseptions, This is the best method and what i needed,  api-client.ts file got class ApiClient we can modify that like below
response(response) condition in .withInterceptor catchs the error

```
  export class ApiClient {
      http:HttpClient = null;

      constructor(aurelia:Aurelia, auth:AuthenticationService) {
        let httpClient = new HttpClient();
        httpClient.configure(httpConfig => {
          httpConfig
            .withDefaults({
              headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/json'
              }
            })
            .withInterceptor({
                request(request) {
                    if (!auth.isAuthenticated()) {
                        aurelia.setRoot('authentication');
                    };
                request.headers.append('Authorization', 'bearer ' + auth.accessToken);

                 return request;
               }
                response(response) {
                console.log(`Received ${response.status} ${response.url}`);
                return response; // you can return a modified Response

                }
            })
          .useStandardConfiguration()
          .withBaseUrl(config.api_endpoint);
        });
        this.http = httpClient;
      }
    }
```